# Un-hilighting a jquery maphilight area in an Image map

Tags: jquery, imagemap

Been struggling with this for a few hours now. I have an imagemap and I am using the jQuery Maphilight plugin to highlight the different areas of an image map.

The plugin is working fine but i couldn't find a way to un-highlight the active areas. I tried clearing the canvas.

Markup:

```
<img src="someImage" usemap="#levelMap" id="floorplan" />
<map name="levelMap">
  <area id="area1" shape="poly" coords="316,56,334,56">
  <area id="area2" shape="poly" coords="460,84,537,85">
</map>
```

Code:

```
$('area').eq(0).attr('data-maphilight','{"fillColor":"000000","alwaysOn":true}'
$('#floorplate').maphilight();
```

This highlights the first area as expected. Now, i am listening for a custom event which tells that the second area is the active one and not the first. At this point,

```
$('area').removeAttr('data-maphilight'); // Remove the attribute from all area elements.
$('area').eq(1).attr('data-maphilight','{"fillColor":"000000","alwaysOn":true}' // Add attribute for the next area.
$('#floorplate').maphilight(); // Call the plugin again to execute on the latest active area.
```

Doing the above highlights the new area but doesn't remove the old one even though it doesn't have the maphilight attribute. I even tried removing the entire 'map' element and adding it back again but the plugin seems to save the state.

So, the final output i need is an image map that works similar to a slideshow. One area hilights, then moves on to the next.

Any ideas?

Comment: i haven't seen an imagemap since 2001 :)

Comment: in all seriousness, why not use a div with a sprite graphic for the different states? it would probably be easier to work with

Comment: @Brad - In all seriousness, this image is a CAD rendered floorplate and the 'area' elements I am talking about are Units inside that floorplate. So yeah, sprites not an option. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. For example if you would like to "un-hilight" `area1`, you could do:

```
$('area#area1').unbind('.maphilight');
```

It's similar to what I tried on mahilight's example page: http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html. Once you are there try running the following in your console:

```
$('area:eq(1)').unbind('.maphilight');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling with same issue. What i did is i wrapped image and map element in separate div and then applied maphilight and issue resolved.

```
<div id='image'> <image src='yourimage' class='mapclass' usemap='#mymap'></div>
```

and then your `<map>` tag as follow

```
<div id='map'> <map name='mymap'> <area></area> </map> </div>
```

then apply `$('.mapclass').maphilight()`
it will work like a charm